# Having injured or Injuring

Tags: perfect-constructions

> A remote-controlled bomb exploded outside a hotel near the town square yesterday, _ at least 12 people.
> A having been injured
> B having injured
> C injured
> D injuring

I think D is correct, but somebody argues that B is, saying it's a shorthand of "which has injured":

> A remote-controlled bomb exploded outside a hotel near the town square yesterday, which has injured at least 12 people.

How do you think, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way that B could be correct is if the bomb injured 12 people *before* it exploded.

That is grammatically correct, but it is not how bombs work.

So D is the only correct answer. It's not short for anything, it is a participle phrase.  "Which has injured" would also be wrong, unless you mean that the *town square* has injured 12 people (and that's not how town squares work).